# Java MiniGame Hiding Letters

Tags: java

Hey guys im new to Java and atm im creating a Text Adventure game =) 
so, to unlock systems i want a feature called minigame.
a black frame should hide letters inside of it and if you mark them with 
your mouse you should be able to see them..at the end you have to put
the correct word into a textField.
Can some1 give me some cheats for that? :D

Comment: Yes, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help) is the first cheat and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) another cheat I would suggest you to go through ;)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I would consider changing the wording of your question because people on here are very sensitive about wording and specificity, which helps us to better answer your question.

I assume that by "cheats" you mean shortcuts to acomplishing this. There is not a very straightforward way to do this in Java, but I would certainly reccommend writing this game using javaScript with the jQuery library. JQuery has a method .hover() that would be very useful here, and you could code the interactive rectangle in html and CSS.

Also, javaScript is similar to Java in case learning Java is your overall goal. That is my "cheat," using these two tools instead of Java for this purpose. Otherwise you would have to use a java graphics library which might be a little complicated for a beginner.

I would reccommend using Code Academy since it was how I originally learned how to develop webpages and was incredibly helpful to me as a beginner: https://www.codecademy.com

Comment: thx mate =) as I said im new to programming. And i just wanted a solution based on java swing..sorry my bad wording

Comment: No problem, there is certainly a learning curve to programming. Next time I would suggest tagging the language and the package you are using. But in that case, this might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25393134/how-to-get-mouse-hover-event-in-java-swing                                                                                       Also, if my answer or this comment was useful and clear, then don´t forget to upvote :)